# p5.js: drawing an element outside draw

Tags: javascript, p5.js

My question is simple. In p5.js, there is a draw function. I think you can only draw elements (like a rectangle from inside this function). I want to draw a single rectangle during a function that is outside draw. (only triggered by certain events). Anyone have any clue as to how I can do this?

EDIT: have tried just drawing outside with rect(x,y,w,h) does not work
also have tried making a this.drawRect = function() {} within the draw(), no luck as well

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: https://jsbin.com/widinuruna/edit?html,css,js,output

```
function setup() { 
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  noLoop() // make draw to only be called once
} 

function draw() { // usually called 60 times / s
  background(220); // clears the canvas (including your rect, if drawn before)
}

setTimeout(()=> {
  rect(20,20,50,50)
}, 300)
```

Your rect was probably drawn before you could see it :)

ref: https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/draw

---

Let's say you what a box to be drawn at cursor on mouse press. Depending on your use case, you might either want to:

- redraw everything continuously

  ```
  // try changing 60 to eg. 1, and click fast while moving the cursor
  // - you'll see it will still only update once a second
  function setup() {
    createCanvas(400, 400)
    frameRate(60) // make draw be called 60 times/s (default?)
  }
  // keeping "state" as an object is a common practice... 
  const state = {x: 0, y: 0} // initialize state
  // ...then it can be updated whenever, eg. on interaction,
  //  without caring about the drawing
  function mousePressed() {
    // update state on interaction
    state.x = mouseX; state.y = mouseY
  }
  // ...the screen will then update independently
  function draw() {
    // (avoid changing the state here)
    background(220) // clear the canvas
    rect(state.x, state.y, 50, 50) // draw according to state
  }
  // by separating "logic" (eg. changing the state) and drawing:
  //  - a "game" will "behave" the same even at different fps,
  //    important for multiplayer etc.
  //  - code will be simpler to reason about and work with, etc
  ```
- only redraw when necessary

  ```
  // using noLoop() in setup, draw() will only be called once initially
  // then, either use rect in eg. mousePressed, or:
  // keep using state, but manually call redraw() after changing the state
  pros = "more efficient if less redraws then eg. 60fps is needed"
  cons = "need to know when to invoke redraw,"
       + "possibly makes code a bit more complicated"
  ```
- only redraw what's necessary

  ```
  // using either point 1 or 2, but in addition keeps track of the
  // previous state, then, only redraws the part of the screen necessary
  // eg. instead of calling background(200), which is the same as:
  fill(200); rect(0,0,width,hight); fill(255) // to clear the screen (and restore fill color)
  fill(200); rect(oldState.x,oldState.y,50,50); fill(255) // clearing only what was previously drawn
  /* followed by */ rect(state.x,state.y,50,50); // as normal
  // (assumes noStroke() is called in setup)
  pros = "possibly much more efficient if large canvas"
  cons = "possibly more complicated"
  ```